# Socrata and DELETE request

Tags: socrata

I have recently found out how to delete rows by ID with the SODA API, but all of them were done through HTTP POST requests.

Whenever I use DELETE requests, no matter what content is sent, it deletes the entire contents of my database. On the documentation page for direct [Direct Row Manipulation](http://dev.socrata.com/publishers/direct-row-manipulation.html), the sample request for HTTP DELETE (application/json) does not work:

```
[
  {
    "typ": "delete",
    "id": "row-evac~sxbs~gm8t"
  }
]
```

Is the DELETE part of the SODA API functioning correctly? Or is the POST request the preferred choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is described on http://dev.socrata.com/publishers/direct-row-manipulation.html, you just need to issue the following request, replacing `<ROW IDENTIFIER HERE>` with the row identifier of the row you wish to delete.

```
DELETE /resource/hgqn-vki9/<ROW IDENTIFIER HERE>.json HTTP/1.1
Host: soda.demo.socrata.com
Authorization: Basic [REDACTED]
X-App-Token: [REDACTED]
```

For example, to delete this row: soda.demo.socrata.com/id/4tka-6guv/00388609.json (the row identifier is "00388609") you would issue the DELETE request to: https://soda.demo.socrata.com/id/4tka-6guv/00388609.json